# How to deal with IResourceStreamWriter API change in Wicket 1.5?

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

In Wicket 1.4, I had a custom AbstractResourceStreamWriter (used in a custom kind of Link for streaming a file that gets generated on the fly):

```
private AbstractResourceStreamWriter resourceStreamWriter() {
    return new AbstractResourceStreamWriter() {
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream output) {
            try {
                reportService.generateReport(output, report);
            } catch (ReportGenerationException e) {
               // ... 
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String getContentType() {
            return CONTENT_TYPES.get(report.getOutputType());
        }
    };
}
```

In Wicket 1.5, the **[IResourceStreamWriter](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/util/resource/IResourceStreamWriter.html) interface has been changed so that the method gets a [Response](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/request/Response.html) instead of OutputStream**. It is somewhat confusing that the IResourceStreamWriter javadocs still talk about OutputStream:

> Special IResourceStream implementation that a Resource can return when
>   it directly wants to write to an output stream instead of return the
>   IResourceStream.getInputStream()
>
> ...
>
> Implement this method to write the resource data directly the the
>   given OutputStream.

Anyway, I don't see a quick way of getting an OutputStream from the Response.

Given that I have a method (the call `generateReport(output, report)` in above code) which expects an OutputStream to write into, what's the simplest way to make this work again?

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
reportService.generateReport(baos, report);
response.write(baos.toByteArray());
```

or something similar?

Comment: Thanks, I suppose that could work. (Can't verify right now as there are other 1.5 migration issues unsolved.) Btw, the variable needs to be defined as ByteArrayOutputStream; I took the liberty to edit your answer.

Comment: Thanks... I removed it in one of my previous edits without involving an IDE. I too can't test it right now since I can't access my wicket projects from work...

Answer (score 0):

There is a org.apache.wicket.request.Response#getOutputStream(). But again I'm not sure this is the same as in 1.4.x. In 1.5 this will buffer what you write in the output stream. Where the javadoc says it shouldn't be buffered.